# How to jump into a page through hyperlink WordPress menu

Tags: wordpress

I want to add a custom link into WordPress menu which jumps to a page specific area, Like I have contact form on the bottom of my website and I don't want the contact link in the menu to go to a different page, I want it to jump to bottom,
I am using WordPress custom menu custom link 
Hyperlink: #contact
but it is reloading page and going to next page, I want to jump to bottom not to go other page,

Comment: It's impossible for `#contact` as a hyperlink to be reloading the page unless there is some kind of JavaScript event firing when you click these links

Comment: I don't know what JavaScript should be added, can you please explain?

Comment: I'm just suggesting that JavaScript may be the problem. The default action of clicking a link like that is to **not** reload the page.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both link and contact form are in the same page, and contact form has an id of "contact", The link should be something like this:

```
<a href="#contact">go to contact section</a>
```

Comment: you are right heidar Mostafa, but the problem is how to add this in wordpress menu, Wordpress only have option in custom menu Name and Hyperlink, how to add this into wordpress custom menu?

Comment: from appearance > menus I selected "Custom Links" and in the URL field I inserted "#contact" and It worked well